# How to add vault (Hashicorp) entity to an existing group via CLI

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

I have several entities (users) in vault implementation. These entities have alphanumeric ids. I also have a group called ops. This group also has an alphanumeric id.

I have looked at the Hashicorp's documentation here:

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/identity

However, it doesn't cover this particular use case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update the target group’s entities (the `ops` group in your case)

In a few steps

- 1: Read the group data: read the current state of the group
- 2: update the identity entity IDs list to add the entities you want to add to this group
- 3: post the group update with this `member_entity_ids` list

https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/identity/group#update-group-by-id

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: Very disappointing that there is no cli command for this...

Comment: @pkaramol you can use the CLI too (using `foobar` as the group name in this example),

get the current list of users for a group: `vault read identity/group/name/foobar -format=json | jq .data.member_entity_ids`

list of all isers and their entity ids: `vault read /identity/entity/id list=true -format=json | jq -r '.data.key_info | keys[] as $k | "\($k):\(.[$k].aliases[] | (.mount_type + ":" + .name))"'`

update the members of the group with `vault write identity/group/name/foobar member_entity_ids=...` 

I used JSON output and `jq` to fetch specific fields (optional, nice to have),